# Node.js & Webpack, full restart when a new file is created

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm currently using [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) to automatically reload my Webpack application when a file is changed. This is working great.

On startup, my app checks the files in the project's folders, that data is then used within the webpack.config.js to make the app work properly.

I do this by using `fs.readdirSync`:

```
fs.readdirSync('pages', { withFileTypes: true }).forEach(entry => {
  // Do something with the files here
}
```

When I just need to reload a file everything works fine as the files within the app are the same. However when I add a new file that wasn't considered by my startup script, the only way I can make Webpack aware of it is by manually restarting (CTRL+C + npm start) Webpack.

I've looked at the Webpack documentation and I can't find any mention of automating a full restart. Just reloads.

Is there a Webpack setting or an external package that would allow me fully restart Webpack when a file is added within a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Look for `nodemon` or similar package and integrate it into your workflow.

Comment: Installed nodemon, is there a specific setting to make it watch for new files? I'm lost in the docs

Comment: sorry, but searching for "nodemon restart webpack" isnt giving you any sensible results ? Btw, there is a https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon-webpack-plugin directly for integration with webpack (have not tried it).

Comment: That's what I did, but while this seems to work with adding files, it doesn't work when removing them. Guess I'll just figure it out. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: So it looks like it's not possible to get `nodemon` to reload when a file is deleted.